# Remove tag and contents based on child tag and add a new content - Shellscript xml

Tags: shell-script, xml

Can anyone please guilde me with this. 
I am trying to locate a particular tag, based on it child's contents and remove the parent tag and contents and add a new contents, but cant find an answer. Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE app
PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<app>
<displayname>Admin</displayname>
<filter>
 <filtername>accesslog</filtername>
 <filterclass>com.filter.accesslog</filterclass>
</filter>
<filter>
  <filtername>ServerHealthCheckFilter</filtername>
  <filterclass>com.filter.ServerHealthCheckFilter</filterclass>
</filter>
</app>
```

What I want to do is to search `<filtername>accesslog</filtername>` exists in a `<filter>` block, if it does i want to delete the whole `<filter>` block which the `<filtername>accesslog</filtername>` in its parent and add a new content. So the result would be:

```
<displayname>Admin</displayname>
<filter>
 <filtername>accesslog</filtername>
 <filterclass>com.logclient.filter.accesslog</filterclass>
 <initparam>
   <param-name>logClientName</param-name>
   <param-value>com.logging.AccessLogImpl</param-value>
  </initparam>
</filter>
<filter>
  <filtername>ServerHealthCheckFilter</filtername>
  <filterclass>com.filter.ServerHealthCheckFilter</filterclass>
</filter>
```

I'm just trying my first xsl to delete content first. Here it is:

modifyxml.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output
  method = "xml" 
  version = "1.0" 
  encoding = "ISO-8859-1"
  omit-xml-declaration = "yes"
  doctype-public = "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd"
  indent = "yes"/>
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="filter[filter-name = 'accesslog']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get errors.

```
modifyxml.xsl:8: parser error : error parsing attribute name
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd"
^
modifyxml.xsl:8: parser error : attributes construct error
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd"
^
modifyxml.xsl:8: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag output line 2
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd"
^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not try to parse XML with a shell script. Look for a purpose built tool like `xsltproc`.

Comment: I tried writing xsl. I included that in code. I'm getting errors. Can you help me with that?

Comment: As the error indicates the XSLT is malformed, it seems you have two strings following `doctype-public`.